# Why does the write speed of my SSD significantly decrease after writing to it for a few minutes?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance

I have more than 20 SSDs from Crucial, Samsung, and other companies.

Let's take the example of my Samsung 970 Plus 2TB which I use with a 10 Gbps USB C enclosure. [On the product page](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/us/consumer-storage/internal-ssd/970evoplus/#specs) it says that the SSD has a write speed of up to 3,300 MB/s.

When transferring RAW photos from my camera to this SSD, it sits between 500-1000 MB/s, which is expected via a 10 Gbps enclosure. However, after a short while, the write speed slows down to 30-50 MB/s, which is even worse than that of a mechanical hard drive!

On my Crucial x4 4TB (via a 10 Gbps USB C cable), the behavior was even worse. I was transferring copying some files *internally* from one folder to another. It started out at ~200 MB/s, but then slowed down to 45 MB/s after just *two minutes* of copying files.

I have experienced this behavior across most of my SSDs. Why does the write speed on my SSDs slow down so significantly after writing to them for a few minutes? How do I avoid this? It’s frustrating since I bought all these SSDs to be able to transfer data to them much faster than I would with a mechanical drive.

I did some of my own research and got some possible explanations, but none of them seem plausible:

1. Thermal throttling: I’ve felt these drives and they barely get hot at all during the data transfer. The 970 Plus is in a metal enclosure, connected via a thermal pad. Also, I wouldn’t expect it to throttle after such a short amount of time if it’s being written to at 25% of its rated write speed.
2. Write amplification: From my understanding, this shouldn’t be an issue since this happens even with a newly formatted SSD.

Comment: Per the duplicate most modern fast SSDs have two types of flash. TLC for bulk storage which is only "kindof" fast for writing but is really fast for reading, and a fast SLC cache which buffers incoming writes. Once the SLC is full then you end up using the slower write speed of the TLC flash.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks, this actually did answer my question. It is interesting to know. I've been doing some digging around in spec pages. How would I know how big the SLC cache for a drive? I cannot for the life of me find that information in the spec pages of any of the SSDs I own. I need an SLC cache size of 100-200 GB, about 5-10% of the drive's capacity. But how would I know which SSDs support this?

Comment: It's not really the kind of thing manufacturers want to advertise as it exposes weaknesses they don't really want to tell you about. At best you can look at benchmarks that should expose it like https://www.techpowerup.com/review/solidigm-p44-pro-2-tb-1-tb/6.html

Comment: That benchmark page also has a list of drives and the measured SLC capacity, though I would take that figure with a pinch of salt. It will be in that sort of ballpark but could be some percentage either way due to the fact it is writing from the cache at the same time as accepting data from the host.

Comment: I was cloning via USB and found the quality of adapters vary wildly.  I had good luck with this amazon part B011M8YACM.  I had a variety of USB to SATA laying around, and I had similar to your experiences performance issue with them.  So I bought a few new ones, and they worked much better.

Comment: @Mokubai It's kind of strange to me that something as important as SLC size is not listed on a drive's datasheet. I wonder how it it's not illegal at that point—isn't 3 GB/s basically false advertising if it's only sustained for a minute? I think it would be reasonable if the speed slowdown was to ~500 MB/s, but the actual slowdown is to 50 MB/s which is much slower than the write speed of a spinning hard drive

Comment: @cybernard even with a "good" adapter, I don't think it would affect the amount of data it can dump quickly onto the drive, right? Since that is wholly determined by the SLC cache size

Comment: @SkeletonBow no one wants to be the ones screaming out "look how crap our drives are!" Or "oh hey, everyone else is slightly better for the same price". It's basically the same problem as happened with SMR drives, they're good drives up to a point and then performance goes to shit once the CMR zone is full and the drive has to start emptying it into the SMR zone. I've seen drives literally being able to write tens of GB for a good period then the drives basically go dead for 5 or more minutes before they carry on and pretend they didn't just appear to vanish for 5 minutes.

Comment: Would you want to put that on your datasheets? No, you say "it has these performance figures under our test 'normal use case'" and then you set that use case so the poor performance never shows up. Regardless of whether that use case was completely mythical and had no basis in reality, marketing people are there to sell stuff no matter how crap it is.

Comment: @SkeletonBow I was cloning a bunch of PC from SSD via USB and all the adapters I had on hand had the same problems your experiencing.  I bought a new adapter, and the performance did not go down after a few minutes any more.